# already initialized constant, and required twice

Tags: sinatra

Hi, all,
i think this is a bug about the constant defined in sinatra, let's look my code.

route.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
        C = "this is a test for constant"
        "Hello World!"
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rack'
gem 'sinatra'
```

config.ru

```
require './route'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Starting the web server, we will see the below

```
$ rackup 
[2011-10-08 19:54:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-10-08 19:54:36] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i686-linux]
[2011-10-08 19:54:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3268 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0059
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0142
/home/zcdny/repo/test/route.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant C
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0094
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0098
/home/zcdny/repo/test/route.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant C
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0003
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0006
/home/zcdny/repo/test/route.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant C
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0003
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2011 19:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0005
```

## Eidt

Fixing the file route.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
        C = "this is a test for constant"
end

get '/' do
        "Hello World!"
end
```

Now, the server no longer warning the constant be initialized.
But the log of server still appears double 'GET' require ,
 i just want it requires for one to every client required,  that is my question, How to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong about that? If you define the constant twice (which happens if you have two GET requests or a GET and a HEAD request) then that warning will be displayed. You global variables instead. But if you don't have to, try to avoid global state at all cost, otherwise you might run in architectural issues (what if you want to serve more endpoints and globals clash) and make it hard to scale: if you rely on the internal state of a process, will you be able to serve the website from two processes? what about two machines?

Comment: I don't what happened to the sinatra that makes sense to be require twice, see the question, i edit it.

Comment: Still, my answer remains the same: The warning states that you set a constant twice, which you do, in line 4 of your route.rb. Your file is only loaded once, but that line is executed on every request.

Comment: Actually, i add the constant defined to the configure block, that will be not showed the error message. But i really know why the sinatra need to seed twice require for a action every time.

Comment: It does not. It logs twice due to CommonLogger being in your middleware stack twice. That is not related yo your warning, though.

Comment: So, how do we deal with the CommonLogger, i just want it to stack one time.

Comment: Add the `disable :logging` setting to configure that not shows the double of require log, this is the answer.

Comment: This will be fixed in 1.3.2. But, as said, this has nothing to do with require or your constant.